# Why is the question about matrix true

Tags: matrices

if $ad \neq bc$ and $x=ax'+by',y=cx'+dy'$, can be solved to be $x'=px+qy, y'=rx+sy$. Find
$\begin{bmatrix}
   g &h \\ m & t
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   a &b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   p &q \\ r & s
\end{bmatrix}$

This is from my high school exam. The answer is in terms of $g,h,m,t$. However, I don't understand why it's true. What if $\begin{bmatrix}
   a &b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  x'\\y'
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$
and $\begin{bmatrix}
  p & q\\ r & s
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  0& 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer Choices:

\begin{bmatrix}
  t& -h\\
-m & g
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  g& h\\
m & t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  -g& h\\
m & -t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  t& m\\
h & g
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  -g& -h\\
-m & -t
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Where did g,h,m and t come from?

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions are a convoluted way to say that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
or, if you prefer, that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be defined as

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}g & h \\m & t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\r & s\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we observe that

$$M\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}g & h \\m & t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\r & s\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\implies M\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}g & h \\m & t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x' \\y' \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\implies M\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}g & h \\m & t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}$$

Since this is true for all $x,y$, we have

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}g & h \\m & t\end{bmatrix} $$